# Selected option if v-bind: value is object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a bit of a newbie to Vue and am having trouble selecting an option from an option select. Here is my attempt:

```
<select v-model="selected" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="planp" size="4" @change="actualizaplan">
<option v-for="plan in planes" :selected="plan.id == '2'" v-bind:value="{ id: plan.id, precio: plan.precio, descuento: plan.descuento}" v-bind:key="plan.id">
</option>
</select>
```

But, it not selected nothing, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go with this code. As you need to pass the id as value for selection visible in the select field.

```
<template>
 <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required>
        <option selected>Choose Province</option>
        <option v-for="plan in plans" v-bind:value="plan.id" v-bind:key="plan.id" >{{ plan.plan }}</option>
    </select>

Selected Value
    {{selected}}
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default{
data: {
  selected:'2',
    plans: [
      {
      id:1,
      plan:'test',
      descuento:'test descuento'
      },
      {
      id:2,
      plan:'test',
      descuento:'test descuento'
      },
      {
      id:3,
      plan:'test',
      descuento:'test descuento'
      },
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/meetsohail/ngLzvtex/6/

If you want to pass object. Here we go.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required @change="value(selected)">
        <option selected>Choose Province</option>
        <option v-for="plan in plans" v-bind:value="{ id: plan.id, 
        plan: plan.plan,descuento:plan.descuento }" v-bind:key="plan.id" >{{ plan.plan }}</option>
    </select>
    {{selected.id}}
    {{selected.plan}}
    {{selected.descuento}}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but I need to pass the object to v-bind: value:
v-bind: value = "{id: plan.id, price: plan.price, discount: plan.discount}"

To use the other properties, the "plan.id" is not just for me.

Comment: I want to use the object properties outside of the v-for. I want to use the object of the selected option.

Comment: You can pass the object too. I have updated the answer, You can use it to pass an object.